# I need to traverse all subdirectories with batch script including changing working directory?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

There's a program that processes a file and outputs in the working directory.
So this doesn't work:

```
for /r "d:\root folder\" %%i IN (*.xma) do d:\whatever-path\program.exe "%%i"
```

I puts the output in the root folder instead of where the input is.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If `program.exe` output its data in the current active directory and the output must be in the same folder that the input data, you can use

```dos
for /r "d:\root folder" %%i in (*.xma) do (
    pushd "%%~dpi"
    d:\whatever-path\program.exe "%%i"
    popd
)
```

changing the current active directory to the one where the file is stored and, after running your command, restoring the previous active directory

Comment: Cool. Thanks. Meanwhile I came up with something similar:

`for /r "d:\root folder\" %%i IN (*.xma) do (
CD /D "%%~dpi"
d:\whatever-path\program.exe "%%i"
)`

What does the "popd" do? Otherwise it seems like an analog of yours.

Comment: @mzso, `pushd` will change the "drive + current folder" to the indicated one (the same you are doing with `cd /d`), `popd` cancels/restores what the `pushd` has done.